# How can i count the amount of numbers where after 1 there always has to be an odd number?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, combinations, relations

The numbers that can be used are {1,2,3,4,5}.
I was supposed to find a solution using a recurrent relation.Tried solving it and got something looked like this:
$$a_n=2*_{an-2} + 4*a_{n-1}$$
but im missing another element.
I also tried finding the numbers for small n-s manually and then finding the relation and i got this:
$$a_1=5$$
$$a_2=23$$
$$a_3=105$$
$$a_4=482$$
Tried using the formula i found earlier:
$$a_3=2*5+4*23 $$ and then i added a 3 to this.But i couldnt actually integrate this because for $$a_4=2*23+4*105$$ i would have to add 13 ,so i dont know what number i need to add.
The way i found the earlier formula was counting the numbers that start with 1 and continue with 3,5;and then the numbers that start with 2,3,4,5 and continue . What i cant count is the numbers that start with 1 and continue with 1 , because i would have to count a huge amount of numbers.So im not sure how i can do this more efficient.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think $a_2=22$ [1,2], [1,4] plus 20 ways that don't start with 1

Comment: It cant really be [1,4] since theres only three even numbers , so its just [1,3] and the 20 others

Comment: What are the three even numbers? (I only see 2 even digits)

Comment: It is true that $a_n$ is the number of $n$ digit numbers satisfying the requirement?

Comment: My bad im kinda dumb, i meant odd numbers. I shall change the whole post

Comment: Please tell us whether an odd digit MUST appear IMMEDIATELY after $1$   e.g.  is 123 OK

Comment: No 123 is not ok, it should be immediately after the 1 .however after the odd number it doesnt matter(unless its 1). Sorry for not explaining it earlier. And yes an is that number

Comment: You never specified what is $n$ and what is $a_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

- $b_n$ be the number of n digit numbers satisfying the requirements with the last digit being 1
- $c_n$ be the number of n digit numbers satisfying the requirements with the last digit not being 1
- So $a_n = b_n + c_n$

$b_{n+1}$ is any legal $n$  digit string followed by a 1
$$b_{n+1} = a_n, b_{n+2} = a_{n+1}$$
$c_{n+1}$ can be made from a legal $n$ digit string ending in 1, followed by 3 or 5. or any  legal $n$ digit string not ending in 1 followed by 2, 3, 4, 5
$$c_{n+1} = 2b_n + 4c_n = 2a_n+2c_n$$
$$c_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1} + 2(2a_n+2c_n)  = 2a_{n+1}+4a_n + 4c_n$$
So
$$ a_{n+1} = 3a_n + 2c_n \tag 1
$$   $$ a_{n+2} = 3a_{n+1} + 4a_n +4c_n \tag2
$$
eliminate $c_n$ and rearrange to get
$$a_{n+2} = 5a_{n+1} - 2a_n$$

which yields ..
$$a = (5, 23, 105, 479, 2185, ...)$$